# Data layer architecture for WPF Rich-Client?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, architecture, telerik, rich-client-platform

## Background

I need to build a Rich-Client application using .NET. The app needs to handle TreeViewControls and TableViewControls with about 100000 entities. GUI is build with WPF, very likely using Telerik Controls. My question is about the general architecture of the data-layer. I've got some coarse ideas of the concepts, but would highly appreciate your comments / thoughts and hints into which technology I should dig deeper. Here're my thoughts:

## Conceptual Layers

### Presentation Layer

just the WPF Controls, I'd need performant synchronizing of different controls on property changes, but I don't anticipate major problems here.

### Business Layer

creating views (object selections to be displayed in the controls), CRUD operations (modifications done directly with the POCOs), searching (global search, but also limited to a view)

### Repository

holds POCOs in an enitity map, decides weather to load from persistence store

### Persistence-Manager

I'm thinking of using a LocalDB or simple Key-Value Store as (persistent) Client-Cache. So, the Persistence-Manager would try to get an object from the local store. Otherwise get the data from the server. Also, persisting data to the Client-Cache. The data would be available via a webservice. I'm happy to give WCF Data Services a try.

### Persistence-Layers

There would be two parts:
- Local DB connection using an ORM like EF or OpenAccess; or a simple key-value store
- HTTP connection to consume the Web-Service

## Questions

- In a layering like this, how about lazy loading referenced objects? I know EF and other ORMs take care of a lot of the issues I have here, too. But I don't see yet how to plug these frameworks into the above layering. Also, where to track changes? Where to secure consistency when deleting objects? (e.g. deleting references to these objects as well)
- I would eager load whole views (hierarchical structures) and perform Linq to objects to those collections of POCOs. Maybe implement a simple inverted index if Linq performance would become a matter. But how should I best implement global searches on the server? Are there libraries ("Linq to OData") available?
- What do you think about a fully "diconnected" scenario? Holding all data a user needs in a local database. Sync on start / stop and user triggered. I could use an ORM directly on the local DB, with good chances to save a lot of headaches trying to implement a lot of consistency features by hand (using the above layering).
- Or in contrast, forget about the local database and batch eager load most of the needed data. Here I'm concerned about the performance of the webservices (without having experience with OData, WCF). I've build an app using Redis and Python that loads about 200000 business objects quite fast (< 1 min) to the client (the objects are already serialized cached in Redis).

I'll certainly do some prototyping and benchmarking, but to get a good start, any thoughts and recommendations are highly appreciate.

Cheers,

Jan